# How can I define an array inside my formgroup and push data?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function that create my formgroup in my ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {

    //When start component create my form group
    this.variacaoForm = this.fb.group({

      variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup()])

    });


 createFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      atributo: "",
      preco: null,
      listaatributos: [],
      sku: '',
      tipo: '',
      id: '',
      id_produto: '',
      estoque_variacao: 0,
      linkfotovariacao: '',
      created_at: '',
      foto_prin_1: '',
      foto_prin_2: '',
      foto_prin_3: '',
      foto_prin_4: '',
      foto_prin_5: '',
      foto_prin_6: ''
    });
  }
}
```

Note that `listaatributos` must be an array.

I try add one function that push data in this listaatributos array:

```
adicionaAtributo(index: number) {          
  this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[index].listaatributos.push(this.idAtributo);
}
```

But i have this message:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'listaatributos' of undefined

My idea is that i have a reactive form that must be various `variacoes` and inside the `variacoes` must be a `listaatributos` set as array.

Something like:

```
variações: [{"estoque_variacao": 900, "atributos":[12,13]}]
```

This is the tree dom of my `variaçãoForm`:

[Controls dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zytQY.png)
[Value dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPTvQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.variacaoForm.controls` instead of `this.variacaoForm.value` :

```
adicionaAtributo(index: number) {          
  (<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.variacaoForm.controls['variacoes']).controls[index]).controls['listaatributos'].push(this.idAtributo);
}
```

Regards,

Comment: After ['variacoes'].>controls< i have [ts] Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: i updated the answer , can you please check it now  ( a cast to `FormArray` should be added )

Comment: Already tried:  this.variacaoForm.controls['variacoes']['controls'][index].listaatributos.push(this.idAtributo) but now i have Cannot read property 'listaatributos' of undefined

Comment: Tried with your suggestion:     (<FormArray>this.variacaoForm.controls['variacoes']['controls'][index].listaatributos.push(this.idAtributo))
but now i must have: Cannot read property 'listaatributos' of undefined

Comment: Obs: if i try exactly when you did:
" (<FormArray>this.variacaoForm.controls['variacoes']).controls[index].listaatributos.push(this.idAtributo);"

i receive: Property 'listaatributos' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: I updated the answer now , we need to cast the `controls[index]` to a `FormGroup`  , it should work perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
 adicionaAtributo(index: number){ //Adiciona atributo no form group
    this.listAtributos.push({id:this.idAtributo, tipovariacao: this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[index].tipo, valorvariacao: this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[index].atributo})
    const control = (<FormArray>this.variacaoForm.controls['variacoes']).at(index);
    control.patchValue({listaatributos: this.listAtributos});
```